# Requests.post Argumento variable, status 400 bad request

Tags: python, post, python-requests

Estoy tratando de hacer un request.post, y las variables dentro de data=payload no puedo lograr convertirlas en argumentos, lo que termina siendo un bad request cod 400, copio el codigo:

```
import openpyxl
import requests
url = "https://example"
path= "C:\\Users\\Tomas\\Desktop\\COBSUS2.xlsm"
ex = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) 
s= ex.active

headers = {
    'auth': '****',
    'User': '****',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
}
numero= s['J3'].value # Esta es una celda de excel que contiene un numero
mensaje= s['J3'].value # esta es otra celda que contiene un mensaje.

payload =  '{"destination": numero , "messageText": mensaje}'

response = requests.post("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Alguien me puede indicar como pasar los valores strings dentro, ya probe mil formas...

Comment: Tomás, intenta quitándole las comillas al valor de la variable **payload**, pues debe ser un diccionario y no una cadena con forma de diccionario.

Comment: Como bien ha dicho @RodrigoN prueba con esto: `payload =  {"destination": numero , "messageText": mensaje }`

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias a ambos. Probe mil variantes y el codigo que pegue es uno de esas... sin embargo entiendo, gracias por el aporte del concepto. La que resulto ser la solucion fue usar el codigo json.dumps(payload); supongo que será debido al header content-type que especifica 'application/json'.

Comment: Si hallaste la solución, crea una respuesta a tu pregunta con la solución, ganarás buena reputación seguro! :))